# TypeScript compiler error with React Stateless Function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to code a React Stateless Function component in TypeScript. Please see the code below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';

export interface LinkProps {
    view: any;
    className: any;
    params?: any;
    queryParams?: any;
    store?: any;
    refresh: boolean;
    style?: any;
    children: any;
    title?: any;
    router: any;
}

const Link: React.SFC<LinkProps> = (   // <----- Error on this line
    {
        view,
        className,
        params = {},
        queryParams = {},
        store = {},
        refresh = false,
        style = {},
        children,
        title = children,
        router = store.router
    }) => {
    ...
}

export default observer(Link);
```

However the compiler is giving me an error on `const Link`:

src/components/Link.tsx(17,7): error TS2322: Type '({ view, className, params, queryParams, store, refresh, style, children, title, router }: LinkPr...' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent'.
  Type 'void | Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement'.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the version dependencies in my pckage.json file:

```
"@types/react": "^16.0.29",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
"del-cli": "^1.1.0",
"mobx": "^3.4.1",
"mobx-react": "^4.3.5",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"typescript": "^2.6.2"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try React.SFC<LinkProps, {}> ... the msg say :  is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent'. If the error goes away, then we know you can only work with this function with  a state component

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Here's the error: src/components/Link.tsx(17,13): error TS2707: Generic type 'SFC' requires between 0 and 1 type arguments.

Comment: ah, thx for your feedback try:  `const Link: React.SFC<LinkProps> = (props) => { return...your impl}` we forgot the argument

Comment: That could happen if you forgot to write `return`.

Comment: Hi Glen, it's not that because that would just replace my destructuring with a single props variable. In fact, the answer is close @AluanHaddad's comment. There were multiple returns in the body of the code and one of them did not return an element - it said `return console.log(....)`, thus returning a void (porting someone else's code!). So Aluan, if you put down your comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct. Thank you both for helping.

Comment: I am glad you found the issue. It was really just a guess on my part. I think it is interesting that you had a series of branches and a single missing return, maybe it is a good idea to extract logical paths from their branches into local functions to avoid this sort of issue.

Comment: Yep, I will be doing extensive refactoring once I get the code running. Currently porting this from a ES2015 codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove children in interface LinkProps. And I think you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885993/react-16-7-react-sfc-is-now-deprecated)

Have fun.

Answer (score 3):

This happens if you don't return a JSX element. Also if you return a function that returns a JSX element the issue also will happen. To avoid from this issue you can just return `<React.Fragment>` as an empty element and put your function inside it:

```
<React.Fragment>
    {yourFunction()}
</React.Fragment>
```